# How to agregate rows in one column without subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have such structure:

```
with 
pages ( id, sid, text ) as (
  select 1, 1, 'lorem ipsum' from dual union all
  select 2, 1, 'lorem ipsum2' from dual union all
  select 3, 1, 'lorem ipsum3' from dual union all
  select 4, 1, 'lorem ipsum4' from dual ),
responsible ( id, pid, name, sirname ) as (
  select 1, 1, 'Alexey', 'Ivanov' from dual union all
  select 2, 1, 'Igor', 'Petrov' from dual union all
  select 3, 1, 'Dmitriy', 'Shestakov' from dual)
```

and such select:

```
select 
    p.id, p.sid,
    CASE 
       WHEN 1=1 THEN p.text 
       ELSE p.text 
    END AS "Important thing",
    (select listagg (name || '-' || sirname, '; ') within group (order by id) from responsible where pid = p.sid) as "SA"
from 
    pages p
order by 
    p.id;
```

Output:

```
--------------------------
ID  SID Important thing SA
1   1   lorem ipsum Alexey-Ivanov; Igor-Petrov; Dmitriy-Shestakov
2   1   lorem ipsum2    Alexey-Ivanov; Igor-Petrov; Dmitriy-Shestakov
3   1   lorem ipsum3    Alexey-Ivanov; Igor-Petrov; Dmitriy-Shestakov
4   1   lorem ipsum4    Alexey-Ivanov; Igor-Petrov; Dmitriy-Shestakov
```

It's work as i want. It adds to every pages.id all responsible.name+sirname's.
But i don't like that i use  nested query, because there are over9000 pages.sid in real data base. So i'm afraid that this sql query will be not so fast and db admins will punish me :)

I know, that i can use JOINs, but i dont know how to agregate all name+sirname for every pages.sid. I think, i can use listagg, but as i know Oracle can't 'group by' aliases ("Important thing").

So, I need your advice. It's not so important for me to make this query a bit faster, i want to know how can i solve this task in another way.

Comment: You should include the output you want or already have.

Comment: Oracle has a smart optimizer.  Don't worry about using subqueries or CTEs.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen done,

Comment: @GordonLinoff but it's intresting for me, how can i do this not only with subquery

Comment: @newSqlz I attempted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a subquery in the `SELECT` clause, you could instead join to a subquery which does the text aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.sid,
    p.text AS "Important thing",
    r.sa
FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        pid,
        LISTAGG (name || '-' || sirname, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS sa
    FROM responsible
) r
    ON r.pid = p.sid
ORDER BY p.id;
```

Your current approach uses a correlated subquery, which Oracle probably can't optimize much.  This join approach uses a non correlated subquery, and Oracle has tricks up its sleeve to make it run faster.

Answer (score 0):

In this case You can simplify your query:

```
select p.id, p.sid, p.text, 
       listagg (name || '-' || sirname, '; ') within group (order by r.id)  SA
  from pages p 
  left join responsible r on r.pid = p.sid
  group by p.id, p.sid, p.text
  order by p.id;
```

Comment: no, i cant. i have 1 column with alias. this "CASE" construction is just for example, but in real query i have to use case and aliases